# Aggregate SQL data - MS SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I have some trouble with grouping the data by the order number and aggregating the "support columns" while selecting always the "highest" value.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ OrderNumber ║ PhoneSupport ║ ServiceSupport ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 0000000001  ║ 0020         ║                ║
║ 0000000001  ║ 0010         ║ 0030           ║
║ 0000000001  ║ 0010         ║ 0020           ║
║ 0000000002  ║              ║ 0030           ║
║ 0000000002  ║ 0030         ║                ║
║ 0000000003  ║ 0020         ║                ║
║ 0000000003  ║ 0030         ║                ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

In this example the output should be like this.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ OrderNumber ║ PhoneSupport ║ ServiceSupport ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 0000000001  ║ 0020         ║ 0030           ║
║ 0000000002  ║ 0030         ║ 0030           ║
║ 0000000003  ║ 0030         ║                ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

So far I have often read in various forums something about cursors but I don't like to use it.

My idea was to use the over clause but I am not sure if it is a solution for that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, do `MAX` on the columns you want the "highest" value for.

```
select OrderNumber, max(PhoneSupport), max(ServiceSupport)
from tablename
group by OrderNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. I simplified the problem in my question, with your short but correct answer I recognized that the problem is in the cte before...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group By` and `Max` and then wrap the query in parent to do `Order By` on aggregate columns. Example shown below.

```
select * 
from (
    select OrderNumber, max(PhoneSupport) as PhoneSupport, max(ServiceSupport)  as ServiceSupport
    from tablename
    group by OrderNumber) aa
Order By aa.PhoneSupport
```

Comment: That derived table is unneeded.

Comment: Can't you just put the ORDER BY at the end, without using a derived table? Or is that some kind of MS SQL Server limitation?